# How can I trigger an action from a tab bar item?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

I have a little problem with adding actions on UITabBarItems. I am not using a TabBarController, just the tabbar with items.

I have tried the following in viewDidLoad:

```
[_myTabItem performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myfunction:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

This is causing a `Unrecognized Selector sent to instance` exception.

Have anyone dealt with similar problem?

Comment: does the definition of myfunction exist in your code (myfunction:(id)var)

Comment: please respond to the any of the answers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
[_myTabItem performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myfunction:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

from the above line of code its is clear that `myfunction` having an argument , but you are not passing any argument ,you set `withObject:nil`

Either pass required parameter for `myfunction` ,or just use simple `myfunction { }`

Answer (score -1):

I’m not sure what you’re trying to accomplish using the `performSelectorOnMainThread` call. That just sends the tab bar item the `myfunction:` message, and obviously the bar item does not respond to that.

I don’t think the tab bar items are supposed to trigger actions. They are just building blocks for the tab bar, which then sends you – the delegate – all events as described by the `UITabBarDelegate` protocol. The protocol includes a `tabBar:didSelectItem:` method, which is how you respond to a tab bar item being pressed. (But in general, don’t think about tab bar items being pressed, think about tabs being selected.)